# Tooltips within ngx-datatable are partially hidden behind row borders

Tags: angular, tooltip, twitter-bootstrap-4, ngx-datatable

Tooltips within an ngx-datatable are partially hidden behind row borders.

I tried changing the z-index for *.tooltip-inner*. But it didn't had an effect.

Any ideas why, how can it be fixed?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cvaq2e?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Move over the Edit buttons, the tooltips are behind the row borders.

- **Table version:** 11.2.0 with bootstrap theme
- **Angular version:** 5.2.3
- **Browser:** firefox, chrome
- **Language:** TS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stackblitz thing doesn't work so I'm guessing slightly as to what tooltips you are using. If you're using ng-bootstrap, you should be able to add

`container="body"`

as attribute to each element that triggers the tooltip.

Comment: Worked instantly. thx. NgbTooltipConfig.container is null by default. Any idea why "body" is not the default? Which situations do speak against setting "body" as a default?

Comment: No idea why, I almost always use body for tooltips so it would make sense at least for me to have that as default. But great it worked for you. I would appreciate it if you could mark my answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

To have a global configuration I added the following in my core.module:

```
export function NgbTooltipConfigFactory() {
  const config = new NgbTooltipConfig();
  config.placement = 'bottom';
  config.container = 'body';
  return config;
}

@NgModule({
  providers:
    {
      provide: NgbTooltipConfig, useFactory: () => NgbTooltipConfigFactory(),
    }
```